# Why people use AdobeXD if it cannot generate (reasonably well structured) HTML and CSS?

Tags: website-design, tools

As a person who had seldom to do with web design issues, I see all the enthusiasm around AdobeXD and I don't understand it. It would be justified in my opinion, if I could design my site and then quickly export this design to static HTML/CSS (or a static Android app, for example). But it does not do that, although it does have a plugin with such purpose - but the resulting HTML/CSS looks very bloated.

So what purpose, in simple words, it serves?

Comment: It isn't meant for that? XD stands for eXperience Design not for "design, create and publish my site or app".

Comment: UI/UX Design is as important to Development as Architecture and Engineering is to Construction :)

Comment: "..  and Engineering.." - I don't think we're there yet..

Answer (score 2):

**What does it do**

Adobe XD is a wireframing and prototyping tool to visualize ideas. It makes it easy to quickly visualize an idea for an interface and build a simple clickdummy to test the interaction with other people.

**Ways to export for development**

Yes, it is true that a full export is very bloated and not very human readable. But this is also true for a lot of GUI builders out there (e.g. [Stackoverflow question about Netbeans GUI Builder for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468328/java-gui-builder-or-hand-coding)). You still need a human to code a layout that is minimalistic and human readable.

I found that the following things help me a lot:

1. **Export as svg** and then copy it into your HTML.
2. Share prototype and then use the development view to **inspect css styles**

Adobe XD is similar to other wireframing programs such as Figma or Sketch. I am also in no way affiliated with Adobe.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question, **Why people use AdobeXD if it cannot generate (reasonably well structured) HTML and CSS?**

Adobe XD is a design tool for designing web and mobile apps. Adobe defines it as:

> "XD empowers designers with the speed, precision, and quality to
> seamlessly **iterate and share interactive prototypes** with team members
> and reviewers across devices and platforms, including Windows, Mac,
> iOS, and Android."

Adobe XD was not made for generating reasonably or well strutted HTML & CSS. It's just a design tool so teams can preview and interact with a prototype for a better idea of how would the final product look and feel like.

Using Adobe XD or similar softwares (Sketch and Figma) is like making the blueprints of your home. And it doesn't matter how talented and quick one is with HTML & CSS, you don't build the house just to have a preview of how it would look like.

Comment: "..you don't build the house.." - I have to remark that quite often static HTML/CSS is not exactly "building the house".

Comment: You're right John Donn. HTML/CSS is not exactly "building the house". Is more like placing the first building blocks of your house. By using HTML you're setting the main blocks and structure with <nav> <footer> <article> and many cool <div>'s with classes and ID's. And the CSS is more like "painting the house". Once you have the main structure (HTML) you make it look cool (CSS). For "full building" you'll need JS, PHP, an other things as well to make your house a livable place where things work, but that part is out of the topic.